# Mathematical Writing: Put Background Material in separate section on its own?

Tags: article-writing

When writing a mathematical journal or thesis, where is the best place to put the background material like theorems and definitions?

Currently I am thinking of two options:

1) Place it in a separate section on its own

2) Put the theorems/definitions individually at the start of each appropriate section.

For example, let's say in the paper Theorem 1 to 10, and Definition 1 to 10 are needed. (These Theorems are known results from books/other papers.)

Should I:

1) Put all the above in one section (e.g. after the introduction).

2) Put them in the relevant sections just as they are about to be used.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I would think that it is best to look at the journal articles or ask the folks who review inputs for the journal as they seem to all have slightly different rules.